# Hostname resolution fail when submiting a job

Tags: python, docker, apache-spark, apache-iceberg

I am following the [quickstart](https://iceberg.apache.org/spark-quickstart/) guide, and using jupyter notebook everything seems to work fine. However when submitting a script with `spark-submit` or configuring the `SparkSession` programmatically I am getting:

`UnknownHostException: rest: nodename nor servname provided, or not known` .

`rest` is the name of container configured in the docker compose (the one provided in the quick-start). I've copied the `spark-defaults.conf` to configure the spark session:

```
builder = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.appName("MyApp") \
    .config('spark.jars.packages', 'org.apache.iceberg:iceberg-spark-runtime-3.5_2.12:1.4.2,org.apache.iceberg:iceberg-aws-bundle:1.4.2') \
    .config("spark.sql.extensions", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.demo", "org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.demo.type", "rest") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.demo.uri", "http://rest:8181") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.demo.io-impl", "org.apache.iceberg.aws.s3.S3FileIO") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.demo.warehouse", "s3://warehouse/wh") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalog.sandbox.s3.endpoint", "http://minio:9000") \
    .config("spark.sql.defaultCatalog", "demo") \
    .config("spark.sql.catalogImplementation", "in-memory")
spark = builder.getOrCreate()

newData = spark.createDataFrame(packages).alias("newData")
```

sshing in the spark container was able to make curl requests to the endpoint `http://rest:8181/v1`.

The full stacktrace:

```
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/Users/guilhermecastro/Documents/raspadinha/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/jars/ivy-2.5.1.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/guilhermecastro/Documents/raspadinha/iceberg.py", line 25, in <module>
    newData.writeTo("warehouse.datasets").createOrReplace()
  File "/Users/guilhermecastro/Documents/raspadinha/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 2100, in createOrReplace
  File "/Users/guilhermecastro/Documents/raspadinha/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
  File "/Users/guilhermecastro/Documents/raspadinha/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py", line 179, in deco
  File "/Users/guilhermecastro/Documents/raspadinha/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o55.createOrReplace.
: org.apache.iceberg.exceptions.RESTException: Error occurred while processing GET request
    at org.apache.iceberg.rest.HTTPClient.execute(HTTPClient.java:311)
    at org.apache.iceberg.rest.HTTPClient.execute(HTTPClient.java:226)
    at org.apache.iceberg.rest.HTTPClient.get(HTTPClient.java:327)
    at org.apache.iceberg.rest.RESTSessionCatalog.fetchConfig(RESTSessionCatalog.java:862)
    at org.apache.iceberg.rest.RESTSessionCatalog.initialize(RESTSessionCatalog.java:173)
    at org.apache.iceberg.rest.RESTCatalog.initialize(RESTCatalog.java:72)
    at org.apache.iceberg.CatalogUtil.loadCatalog(CatalogUtil.java:239)
    at org.apache.iceberg.CatalogUtil.buildIcebergCatalog(CatalogUtil.java:284)
    at org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog.buildIcebergCatalog(SparkCatalog.java:143)
    at org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog.initialize(SparkCatalog.java:555)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.Catalogs$.load(Catalogs.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.CatalogManager.$anonfun$catalog$1(CatalogManager.scala:53)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.getOrElseUpdate(HashMap.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.CatalogManager.catalog(CatalogManager.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.CatalogManager.currentCatalog(CatalogManager.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.LookupCatalog.currentCatalog(LookupCatalog.scala:34)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.LookupCatalog.currentCatalog$(LookupCatalog.scala:34)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.ResolveCatalogs.currentCatalog(ResolveCatalogs.scala:27)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.LookupCatalog$CatalogAndIdentifier$.unapply(LookupCatalog.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.ResolveCatalogs$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(ResolveCatalogs.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.ResolveCatalogs$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(ResolveCatalogs.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsDownWithPruning$2(AnalysisHelper.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(origin.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsDownWithPruning$1(AnalysisHelper.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:168)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:164)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsDownWithPruning$4(AnalysisHelper.scala:175)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:699)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsDownWithPruning$1(AnalysisHelper.scala:175)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:168)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:164)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperators(AnalysisHelper.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperators$(AnalysisHelper.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.ResolveCatalogs.apply(ResolveCatalogs.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.ResolveCatalogs.apply(ResolveCatalogs.scala:27)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$2(RuleExecutor.scala:222)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:126)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft$(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:122)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1(RuleExecutor.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1$adapted(RuleExecutor.scala:211)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:431)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$$executeSameContext(Analyzer.scala:226)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.$anonfun$execute$1(Analyzer.scala:222)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.AnalysisContext$.withNewAnalysisContext(Analyzer.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.execute(Analyzer.scala:222)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.execute(Analyzer.scala:188)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$executeAndTrack$1(RuleExecutor.scala:182)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.executeAndTrack(RuleExecutor.scala:182)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1(Analyzer.scala:209)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.markInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.executeAndCheck(Analyzer.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$analyzed$1(QueryExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$2(QueryExecution.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.withInternalError(QueryExecution.scala:546)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$1(QueryExecution.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:900)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executePhase(QueryExecution.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:142)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriterV2.runCommand(DataFrameWriterV2.scala:196)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriterV2.internalReplace(DataFrameWriterV2.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriterV2.createOrReplace(DataFrameWriterV2.scala:134)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: rest: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:933)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1543)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:852)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1532)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1384)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1305)
    at org.apache.iceberg.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:43)
    at org.apache.iceberg.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:141)
    at org.apache.iceberg.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:447)
    at org.apache.iceberg.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalExecRuntime.connectEndpoint(InternalExecRuntime.java:162)
    at org.apache.iceberg.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalExecRuntime.connectEndpoint(InternalExecRuntime.java:172)
    at org.apache.iceberg.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ConnectExec.execute(ConnectExec.java:142)
    at org.apache.iceberg.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at org.apache.iceberg.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:192)
    at org.apache.iceberg.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at org.apache.iceberg.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpRequestRetryExec.execute(HttpRequestRetryExec.java:96)
    at org.apache.iceberg.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at org.apache.iceberg.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ContentCompressionExec.execute(ContentCompressionExec.java:152)
    at org.apache.iceberg.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at org.apache.iceberg.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:115)
    at org.apache.iceberg.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.ExecChainElement.execute(ExecChainElement.java:51)
    at org.apache.iceberg.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:170)
    at org.apache.iceberg.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:123)
    at org.apache.iceberg.rest.HTTPClient.execute(HTTPClient.java:274)
    ... 89 more
```